# After ‘make clean’ still can't re-make, 'make: Nothing to be done for' raised, MacOS

Tags: macos, makefile, fortran, gnu-make, gfortran

My current Operating system is MacOS. And I used 'zsh' as my default Shell.

I'm trying to compile a software named 'OpenCalphad' [OpenCalphad](http://www.opencalphad.com/). (It was written in Fortran). For some reasons, I want to re-compile it. So I used the `make clean` command, and then use `make Makefile-MacOS`. But it showed **make: Nothing to be done for `Makefile-MacOS'**.

Could anyone give me some suggestions? Really appreciate your help!!

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. You should do not  do `make Makefile-MacOS`, there is some flag for it, check the manual. Try `make -f Makefile-MacOS`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It works!